# Is the PGP version number required?

Tags: gnupg, pgp, openpgp

ASCII-armored GnuPG data usually has a `Version` header:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: GnuPG v2.0.22 (GNU/Linux)

hQIMAxfkjOs8YMF+AQ//e9yWfwKBddUX/1YfghKfF/xJhuirYmAdxhsLaO5Fj0QJ
yYZUQ6mtBH6L9J0hxfvsfLvH0+28jw//HTd4iAvczW99Qo0jH/BYfZLeMeh3B42J
Ws7iS5WUdhgXrT/EkBO2OkEPjuRbolU7p8XnX6tD/bazeI5FViwyfLb1EBffKYXG
...
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

If you remove the version line, the data still decrypts just fine, but starts off with this error message:

```
gpg: invalid armor header: hQIMAxfkjOs8YMF+AQ/8CZO9fuB8CImJN7Kl7O0n18Uvk+B9wgCBiS0E2ZIr4sjJ\n
```

Why is the `Version` string included? Is this extra line of information beneficial to anyone, or even required anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Version` header is purely informative; my guess is that it's included to make compatibility bugs easier to discover (e.g. if a client is unable to decrypt 10 messages, and all 10 were made by the same version).

The error message you're seeing, however, is not caused by lack of `Version`, but by the lack of *empty line* separating headers and body. According to the syntax for OpenPGP armored messages, even if you have zero headers, you still need the separator so that parsers would know that `hQIMAxfkjOs8...` is in fact the body and not just a weird header.